# jquery datatable ajax reload on change event

Tags: jquery, datatables

load the datatable when dropdown list changes. On change event, i want to pass the value of dropdown list to new ajax URL ..

```
    // Dropdown on change event
$('#myDropdown').on('change', function(){

    var myTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable();  // get the table ID


    // I want to call new ajax URL to get different data.
    // How can I pass below options ? 
    "ajax":
        {
            "url": "/Product/GetProductData/5",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "JSON"
        },

    myTable.ajax.reload();

    myTable.ajax.draw();
});
```

As it's explained in the above code, I like to pass different ID which comes from the dropdown list to the ajax call. Can this be possible ? Also, I defined the columns on initailisation document.ready, but do I need to re-defined them on change event ?

**UPDATE :**

This code below actually helped.

```
    $('#SelectedCustomerID').on('change', function () {
        var customerID = $(this).val();

        alert(customerID);

        var table = $('#tbl_product_list').DataTable();

        table.ajax.url("/Transaction/GetProductListData/" + customerID).load();
        table.draw();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a trivial question, you just need to get the new value from dropdown like:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('change', function(){


   var Id = $(this).val(); // gets selected value of dropdown

   var mytable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Product/GetProductData/"+Id
                    }
                });

   myTable.ajax.reload();

   myTable.ajax.draw();
});
```

Comment: this line starting with "ajax": { I used this when i initialise the datatable but not sure how I can pass it to ajax function which is available from API.

Comment: yeah, you don't need double quotes there, and you need to execute ajax call inside the datatables initialization call

Comment: ahhh okay. so basically I need to re-initialise it .. do I need to destroy the existing datatable first ?

Comment: but do I have to re-intialise it every time when dropdown value changes ? is it possible to just re-load the data ?